# fastest replacement DB

Tags: database, performance, optimization, scale

What's the best database setup for WordPress for speed and lots of posts (hundred thousands of rows in posts and post_meta tables)?

While I can cache as much as I can and optimize my queries/PHP as far as can go, such as in the answer for [How to Optimize WP site for millions of posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166448/how-to-optimize-wp-site-for-millions-of-posts/166699) (am in a very similar situation with the OP of that question), that's only one part of optimizing querying loads of rows with speed.

Am thinking of trying to test/benchmark mySQL with tokudb (http://www.tokutek.com/tokudb-for-mysql/), MariaDB (https://mariadb.org/), and MariaDB with tokuDB. Am curious if anyone has tried/tested these or any other replacement DBs with WordPress, can share results, and recommend their fastest setup.

Comment: I would caution against considering anecdotal evidence for performance decisions. You need your _own_ baseline benchmark for starters — what you have working already, how well does it perform, what are specific operations or functions that are bottlenecking.

Comment: Yes. I plan to benchmark everything locally before even thinking of implementing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to post this same query in the TokuDB-users community here...   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tokudb-user

Good luck with your research.

-dave